# Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 or Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 in order to read Excel files?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access-2010, connection-string, oledb

I try to read Excel files using C#.
Which one should I install in order to make work this line  of code:

```
string con = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" 
              + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

- Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 or
- Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016

Or is there another way to read Excel files without the need of installing external programs?

Comment: If it's xlsx then I suggest you use EPPlus https://riptutorial.com/epplus

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, it is both of the file formats  , xlsx  and xls

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid , as far as epplus is concerned does it need any external program or I can run my application in any computer without any other request

Comment: If it is mdb or xls, you could use the jetengine which comes as standard with windows.  No need to install anything.

Comment: @cup, is there anything for both of them , xls and xlsx?

Comment: Not that I know of.  The jetengine I have (w7) will do xls but not xlsx.  Also, it only works in 32-bit.  If you have a look in syswow64\obdcad32 or system32\odbcad32 it should tell you what file extensions it will take.

Comment: You could use the ODBC driver using driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=file" but it needs a dbq parameter.  If you are using this, for xlsx, it needs to be driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*xls, *xlsx, *xlsm, *xlsb)};Dbq=...".  Check the file DSN in  odbcad32 to see what the excel string is.